How to Extract data from rows data collected from logs
Seeking help on how to extract data from rows of data similar to this
Raw Data

and convert data placement to this
Process Data

im having problem to extract "Process X" and populate the next column
Sub Data_Extraction()
    
 Dim R1 As Range, xCel As Range
   Dim Checking As Boolean
   Dim Rng As Range
   
   Set R1 = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
   
   Checking = False
   For Each xCel In R1.Cells
      If InStr(1, xCel.Value, "Start") <> 0 Then
         Checking = True
         
      End If
      
      If Checking = True And InStr(1, xCel.Value, "Full") <> 0 Then
         xCel.Offset(0, 3).Value = xCel.Value
        
        
      End If
             
      
      
      
      If Checking = True And InStr(1, xCel.Value, "Full") <> 0 Then
        xCel.Offset(0, 2).Value = xCel.Offset(0, -1).Value
      
      End If
        
                  
      If InStr(1, xCel.Value, "End") <> 0 Then
         Checking = False
      End If
      
   Next xCel


Have you looked into using Power Query to do this?

no...sadly im not yet informed on how to use Power Query

Agree with @Darren Batrup-Cook about Power Query. I think Data transformation via PQ should be straightforward. Most actions could be done via UI. PQ records actions in M code so they're repeated via query refresh. You could Get Data From Folder to start.

Starting with this data in Excel:


Select Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range and highlight your data in the dialog that appears.


This will open the Power Query Editor.


Next we want to pull out the Process * information from Column2.
Select Add Column > Custom Column

Enter this formula in the Custom column formula box.
Note: This is case sensitive - use if not If
if Text.StartsWith([Column2],"Process") then [Column2] else null
You should end up with a new column with just the Process values in.

Select Transform > Fill > Down

Your table will now look like below:


Next filter Column2 to only those rows that start with Box:

Your table will now look like this:


On the Home table click Close & Load to load this table onto a worksheet.





Option Explicit

Sub Data_Extract()

    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rowLast As Long, rowOut As Long, r As Long
    Dim n As Long, sProcess As String
   
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsIn = .Sheets("Sheet1") ' input data
        Set wsOut = .Sheets("Sheet2") ' results
    End With
    
    rowOut = 2
    With wsIn
        rowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ' scan down input data
        For r = 2 To rowLast
             If .Cells(r, "B") Like "Process*" Then
                 ' save process number
                 sProcess = .Cells(r, "B")
             ElseIf .Cells(r, "B") Like "Box*Full" Then
                 ' write to output sheet
                 wsOut.Cells(rowOut, "A") = .Cells(r, "A")
                 wsOut.Cells(rowOut, "B") = .Cells(r, "B")
                 wsOut.Cells(rowOut, "C") = sProcess
                 rowOut = rowOut + 1
                 n = n + 1
             End If
        Next
    End With
    wsOut.Activate
    wsOut.Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox n & " rows written to " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation
    
End Sub

